# tensorflow generate "fake" random variables for the model

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
tf.set_random_seed(1)
R = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((2,2)), name="random_weights")
with tf.Session() as sess:
   tf.set_random_seed(1)
   sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
   print(sess.run(R))
```

for this piece of code, everytime I run it, it generates different variables, is that any way I make it the same random number initialization, so that I could reoccur the exprinment result and analyze?

Answer (score 0):

Fix operation-level seed as `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((2,2), seed=1)`